# Correct way to use > and < comparison on floats in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point, comparison

I am well aware that using the `==` operator on two floats does not work/is bad practise, however from what I can see, using the `>` and `<` operators on two floats should be valid. However, in my program when I am comparing a very small float value to zero, it seems to simply round the small value to zero, despite the fact that it prints the small number in the console window correctly.
Here is a stripped-down basic example code to show what I mean:

```
float f1 = 0;
float f2 = 5.063425E-12; //or something similarly small
//f2 isn't actually assigned like this, this is a typical value
//as it would be displayed in the console window. it is actually
//formed by a series of multiplications which I haven't shown
//here for simplicity.
if(f2 > f1) {
   System.out.println("Success!");
} else {
   System.out.println("Failed");
}
```

currently it would output "Failed", even though `f2` is moderately larger than zero. the exponent of f1 may be smaller since it is not initialised with a fractional part, could this be affecting the comparison? What is the solution/best practise for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try compiling your own sample code, and you'll see that `5.063425E-12` cannot be represented as a `float`.  Try making your variables `double` instead (that being said, even if I cast to `float`, I still get "success" when I run your code, so I'm not sure if this is actually going to solve your issue).

Comment: well, that is interesting -  I copied and pasted `5.063425E-12` directly from my console window, where the `float` in question had been printed -  I suppose this was the human-readable form of the contents of the `float`, but that was the value shown.

Comment: I changed the type of both floats to double, and the issue persists.

Comment: < and > are not any more valid than ==. If they were, then I could legitimately write `if ( !(a < b) && !(a > b) )`; since this is same as `if ( a == b )` for finite float a, b, then I could legitimately use ==

Comment: I pasted the code into a minimal program, added the needed cast from double to float on the initialization, and ran it. The output was, as expected, "Success!".

Comment: Per OP’s answer, their source code was not what they thought it was.This ought to be closed with the “typo” category.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree that the program part is a typo. However, I am concerned about the general lack of understanding of how floating point comparison behaves. Is it worth writing an answer about that?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Such an answer would be valuable, but I do not think it is good to associate it with a question flawed at the source-code-was-wrong level. You can always pose a new question and answer it yourself. (That is a proper Stack Overflow procedure.)

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, basic error, accidentally left some comments in...

Answer (score -1):

When you multiply a float enough times by a number less than 1 but greater than 0 it will eventually equal 0. What is probably happening is some of your multiplication series are reaching this point while others aren't.

Comment: I have put print-outs in my code showing all the numbers just before they are compared, and they are all distinguished by Java to be greater than zero (for example 2.0045975E-10, 4.4887325E-9) however the issue above remains. Thankyou for you quick response, however